# React does not rerender after setState used in promise in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, promise, setstate

Here is code

```
componentDidMount: function () {
        var self = this,
            templates;
        new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            API.getTemplates(function (err, result) {
                if (!err) {
                    templates = result.templates;
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        }).then(function () {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                _.map(templates,function (template) {
                    console.log("template.companyId " +template.companyId);
                    API.getCompanyById(template.companyId, function (err, result) {
                        if (!err) {
                            template.userId = result.company.userId;
                            resolve();
                        }
                    })
                });
            });
        }).then(function(){
            console.log("templates");
            console.log(templates);
            self.setState({templates: templates});
        });

    },
```

In chrome react tools the state is right.
in render method is calling this.state.templates. But it is null by default

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return {templates: null}
},
```

Looks like rerender is not calling after setState executes. Also if we go on another route, the state in this components will no save, it will be template:null

Comment: Does the console.log fire before the `setState` ?

Comment: What is your `templates` equal when you `log` it inside `then`?

Comment: in **log** inside then shows `[Object, Object, Object]`
@BenjaminGruenbaum idk, how to check it?

Comment: Why don't you keep whole `promise` and `setState` in `componentWillMount`. Why are you waiting for component to mount?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja I have to show something on the page before making requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in making promises inside iterate over array, so if one request is completed method then executed.
Therefore I make array of promises and waiting till everyone succeded.
Here is solution

```
componentDidMount: function () {
        var self = this,
            templates;
        new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            API.getTemplates(function (err, result) {
                if (!err) {
                    templates = result.templates;
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        }).then(function () {
            /* for every template find his userId*/
            let copyTemplate = templates;
            let promises = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < templates.length; i++) {
                promises.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        API.getCompanyById(templates[i].companyId, function (err, result) {
                            if (!err) {
                                copyTemplate[i].userId = result.company.userId;
                                resolve();
                            }
                        })
                    })
                );
            }

            console.log(copyTemplate);
            templates = copyTemplate;
            return Promise.all(promises);
        }).then(function () {
            console.log("templates");
            console.log(templates);
            self.setState({templates: templates});
        });

    },
```